# How do I prove the equivalence of chirality and helicity operators acting on a massless Dirac spinor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, dirac-equation, chirality, helicity

I have massless Dirac equation and chirality and helicity operators which are given as
$$
\hat {P}_{ch}\Psi = \gamma_{5}\Psi, \quad \hat {P}_{h}\Psi = \frac{(\hat {\mathbf S} \cdot \mathbf p)}{|\mathbf p|}\Psi .
$$
I showed that both of them are lorentz invariant operators, they commutes with dirac free hamiltonian and their eigenvalues are $\hat {P}_{ch}\Psi (x) = \pm \Psi (x), \quad \hat {P}_{h}\Psi (x) = \pm \Psi (x)$.

Is it enough for showing their identity? Or I also need to connect the given eigenvalue of $\hat {P}_{h}$ with corresponding eigenvalue of $\hat {P}_{ch}$?

Comment: Have you shown that their eigenvectors coincide? That is, are the $\Psi$s the same?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : yes, I showed it. But is seems that the reason is in signs of energy value: for $p_{0} > 0, p_{0} < 0$ helicity and chirality are connected by the different ways (i.e., left chiral states may correspond to the states of different helicities in dependence on sign of energy).

Comment: Helicity is not a Lorentz invariant operator, since spin,$\bf S$, is not Lorentz invariant.

Comment: @JeffDror - For massless particles, helicity is Lorentz invariant

Comment: Ahh, I thought he meant in general.